# How can you create a limited loop in a batchfile program?

Tags: windows

So basically I have been looking all over the internet trying to find a good way of doing this: Create a limited loop in my batchfile program. I have found no answer.
An example I tried is this:

```
@echo off
echo Hello this is your program.
pause

set i= 0
: test
set i= i + 1

if %i% == 5 goto exit
goto test
: exit
echo good

pause
exit
```

I later found out that I can't just make the "i" variable like that.
When I try to make it a variable it makes me put an input in the command prompt of the program and I don't want that.
I want this to run maybe 5 times, then quit running and go to something else.
If you can answer and help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %i in (1 2 3 4 5) do echo good %i
```

results:

[image]

Okay, here it is in the form you want.  This ran on Windows XP:

[image]

It depends on `set /a` to evaluate the right side as an arithmetic expression.  More than addition is supported.  Type `help set` to learn more.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is the loop where it cycles through the loop up to 5 times then goes on.
Not necessarily an array

Comment: @Whodeyy1234:  Sure.  That is what this does.  That is not an array.  It is a list to iterate through.

Comment: Ok so I put that into my program.bat file and it says that "i was unexpected at this time" also I kinda want it to be unseen sorta thing.
It works in the actual command prompt but not the batchfile

Comment: @Whodeyy1234:  Okay, I have implemented it your way.  See my updated answer above.  Note that I added an `echo I is X` to show that it works internally.

Comment: Thanks so much! You really helped me with my batchfile game!
Hope to see you later!